# Nested object array in objects - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, http, angular, jsonp

I'm using Angular 2 and JSONP to get the value from the api. The api is returning an Object (Nested Objects). Below is the code which I'm trying to use.

**Data**

```
{  
 "adult":false,
 "backdrop_path":"/eIOTsGg9FCVrBc4r2nXaV61JF4F.jpg",
 "belongs_to_collection":null,
 "budget":175000000,
 "genres":[  
  {  
      "id":12,
      "name":"Adventure"
  },
  {  
     "id":18,
     "name":"Drama"
  },
  {  
     "id":14,
     "name":"Fantasy"
  }
 ],
 "poster_path":"/vOipe2myi26UDwP978hsYOrnUWC.jpg",
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
fetchData(){
  return this.jsonp.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/278927?api_key=fd35dcdcfbba840ef2f9ea42c5c55869&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').map(
  (res) => res.json()
);
}
```

**component.ts**

```
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {

 movies = Object;
 constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
   (data) => this.movies = data
 );  
 }
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
{{movies.budget}}    //This is working
{{movies.genres[0].id}}    //This is not working
```

In the HTML Template, I've tried using Elvis Operator, but that is not returning any value. The console log is showing proper data as one single object. **How to get the id and name of different genres?**

```
{{movies?.genres?.id}}
```

is not working, even after providing an index with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working with the knowledge of the index! See my plunker as a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/vI9azM3JkytZ51SifNUa?p=preview

But the index has to be there, so check it first with `*ngIf` or use `*ngFor` to iterate through all possible items.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 *ngIf="names && names.length">Hello {{names[0]}}</h2>

      <h2 *ngFor="let n of names">Hi {{n}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.names = [];

    setTimeout(() => this.names = ['Angular2', 'Name2', 'name3'], 3000);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Well, thanks. I was able to solve it based on console output and hint from your answer. The object name was different thn what I was using.